# latency issue with socket.io(websockets)

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io-1.0

we are planning to create a real time SPA using node.js and we are testing for the latency, please go through the following link :

```
http://173.200.239.98:6060/
```

there are 2 area...when user hover the mouse over a textarea in right side, we are printing the latency in the left side textarea and the latency is in milliseconds. the ques is that latency varies from 0.3 secs to 6 secs..is it normal with web sockets? or am i doing something wrong?

NOTE:- the server is in detroit,usa and i am accessing the server from india chennai.

SOURCE CODE:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'/>
  </head>
  <body style='margin:0px' >

    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>latency in milliseconds</th>
        <th>hover to trigger message</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><textarea id='message' name='message' rows="20" cols="20" ></textarea></td>
        <td><textarea id='hover' name='hover' rows="20" cols="20" ></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($){

            var socket = io.connect();
            var messagearea=document.getElementById("message");
            var workarea=document.getElementById("hover");
            workarea.onmousemove=function(){


                var startTime = Date.now();
                socket.emit('ping',startTime);

            };

            socket.on('pong', function(startTime) {
                var latency = Date.now() - startTime;
                messagearea.innerHTML=  messagearea.innerHTML + latency + '\n';
                messagearea.scrollTop = messagearea.scrollHeight;

            });

        });
    </script>   

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So there's a packet from india --> detroit, some server latency, then a return packet from detroit --> india and it's all TCP so there are confirmation packets going the other way too.  Some noticable lag does not surprise me for going half way around the world.  What were you expecting the latency to be?

Comment: yeah this is what my ques..that is this lag normal ?
or is it something i did wrong? @jfriend00

Comment: I get around 75ms here on your test page from San Jose, CA which seems relatively normal.  I'm on a pretty fast internet connection and San Jose is very well connected to the internet backbone.

Comment: http://173.200.239.98:6060/ 
have u tested this link where my latency test app is running? @jfriend00

Comment: Try doing a `ping -n 20 173.200.239.98` and see what that round trip time is.  That takes your client and server out of the equation and just gives you benchmark for the raw network roundtrip.  I get pretty much the same thing as I get in your app which makes me think your client and server are doing just fine and what you're seeing is the network transit time.

Comment: how to do a ping -n 20 173.200.239.98?? i have no idea .. where and what wil i have to do..! 
can you help me? @jfriend00

Comment: If you're on a Windows box, open up a Command Prompt window and type `ping -n 20 173.200.239.98`.  If you don't know how to open a Command Prompt window, then go to the Start menu and (depending upon which OS version you have), there should be a box where you can type something in the start menu.  Click in that and type `cmd.exe` and hit Enter.  If you're on a different OS, you will have to Google how to run ping.  Every OS can do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get nearly identical results with both a ping test and your app.  Since the ping test takes your client/server out of the equation and uses a well known networking tool - if you get similar results in your app as with a ping test, then your client/server are doing pretty well and not a source of the delay.

Now when you run the test from India to Detroit, you're doing networking half way around the world and across at least one major ocean.  It's not surprising if there is some latency and not surprising if that latency varies.  Just to give you an idea what has to happen is that you send some TCP packets from India to Detroit.  They travel through many, many different routers and service providers and cables/fibers to eventually get to the server in detroit.  Because it's TCP, confirmation of delivery has to be sent back along the reverse route.  Then your server gets the packet and does it's thing sending TCP packets back the other way which again need to be confirmed with return packets.

I ran your app and got these results:

[image]

I ran a ping test with `ping -n 20 173.200.239.98` from my location in San Jose, CA and got these results:

[image]

As you can see, the ping test gave 73-87ms.  Your app game 74-83ms.  Those are basically identical.  It seems like your client and server are doing just fine.

I'd suggest you run your own ping test from your location and see how much of a difference there is between your ping test and your app results.

If you want to see the route that your packets take with some info on transit time to each stop, you can run this command:

```
tracert 173.200.239.98
```

And it will show you the time (in ms) to each successive major hop along the way to the destination.

Comment: for me the minimum is 332ms and maximum is 397ms and avg is 354ms...!
thanx for this..a lot

Comment: i used the command tracert 173.200.239.98 and a lot of info came to the cmd prompt...!

Comment: as u have used my latency app, the data transmission is continuous .. so if i create a buffer which will only send the second data packet when the first is received, will it help reducing the latency?

Comment: @CODeeerrrrrrrr - usually when one has issues with latency, you look to send parallel transmissions, not to wait for other transmissions to complete.  But, I don't understand what problem you're really trying to solve with your latest question so I don't know how to answer.  The time for a single transmission to get its response probably won't change.

Comment: the problem is simple..when web socket are static then why this latency variation is there.. and the how we can call it a real time application as there is a time lag...and real time are supposed to have no time lag... 
i have posted this ques separately also:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25357758/why-latency-varies-in-web-socket-when-its-a-static-connection..
any suggestion over it?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing intrinsic in WebSocket that should cause inconsistent latencies. If that's what you are getting, try doing something else other than WebSocket over the same network route and observe the latencies. For example, ping or FTP.

If you get the same erratic latencies, then you know it's nothing to with the WebSocket connection. If you don't get the same erratic latencies, then it might be something to do with your browser or JavaScript. Perhaps it's slow to process or render the messages?

Basically you need to start peeling away each layer to try and discover which one is adding the latency.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously its dependant on the location you are. I think that's how the internet works.
Latency is pretty low here in Germany: Between 120 and 160 milliseconds... that's fast...